# Adding header files in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, intel-fpga

I wanted to add a header file to my Verilog project. This should be a very easy thing to do. However, it turns out is is not trivial. This my header file. Let's say the file name is parameters.vh

```
`ifndef _parameters_vh_
`define _parameters_vh_
parameter Tm = 2;
parameter Tn = 2;
`endif
```

Then I include it to the top module

```
`include "parameters.vh"
```

But it cannot get synthesized. This is the error message:

Verilog HDL error at parameters.vh(3): declaring global objects is a SystemVerilog feature.
I am wondering if anyone can help me here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Quartus-II, you can enable SystemVerilog features via menu Assignments -> Settings -> Verilog HDL Input.

Otherwise you have to move the inclusion of the parameters file within a module definition like here:

```
module top (x,y);
`include "parameters.vh"
   input x;
   output y;
   assign y = x;
endmodule // top
```

Comment: Although it is legal in SystemVerilog, it is never a good idea to put global definitions outside a module. Much better to put  them in a package and import the package.

Answer (score 1):

it's not a systemverilog issue, just think of what the pre processor is doing when it finds your include line. you can't have parameters outside modules, doesn't make sense.